# Expection Thrown/Exception Unhandled in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: exception, assembly, x86, visual-studio-2019, masm

In the highlighted line of my code, I get the message "Exception thrown at 0x002C36C9 in project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0058C00A"

I have been trying everything to get rid of it but it just doesn't work and I am in desperate need of help. The code is not completely done yet but it should run somewhat. The purpose of the code is to copy elements from arrayS to arrayD starting from the index received from keyboard input. Someone please help me, the code looks perfectly fine so I relaly don't know what is wrong

[See highlighted line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZjTS.png)

I dont really know how to explain what I've tried what I am trying to do is quite simple, which is why I do not understand why I am getting this error.

```
include Irvine32.inc
ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
  arrayS    BYTE    1, 2, 3, 4, 5   ;array (SOURCE)
  numEl = LENGTHOF arrayS
  arrayD    BYTE    numEl DUP(0)    ;array (DESTINATION)
  startIndex    BYTE    ?        ;store the character in this variable
  exit  EQU     <Invoke ExitProcess,0>
  header    BYTE    "----- Array Copier -----",0
  indexq    BYTE    "Index (0 - 4): ",0
  invalidIn BYTE    "Invalid Input. Try again.",0
  termination   BYTE    "----- Program Terminated -----",0



.code

userInput PROC
  mov edx, OFFSET indexq
  call WriteString
  call ReadInt
  call crlf
  mov startIndex, al

  ret
userInput ENDP

displayTitle PROC 
  mov edx, OFFSET header
  call WriteString
  call crlf

  ret
displayTitle ENDP

copyArray PROC

  mov esi, OFFSET arrayS
  mov edi, OFFSET arrayD
  movzx ebx, startIndex
  mov ecx, numEl

copying:
  mov al, [esi + ebx]
  mov [edi], al
  inc esi
  inc edi
  loop copying

  ret
copyArray ENDP

showArray PROC uses ecx
  mov ecx, numEl
  call crlf
  show:
  mov eax, [edi]                ;moving array element to be displayed
  call WriteInt
  call crlf
  add edi, type arrayD      ;moving through array elements to display
  loop show

  ret
showArray ENDP

main PROC
  call displayTitle
  call userInput
  call copyArray
  call showArray

  exit
main ENDP
END main
```

**EDIT** New version based on an answer

```
include Irvine32.inc
ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
  arrayS    BYTE    1, 2, 3, 4, 5   ;array (SOURCE)
  numEl = LENGTHOF arrayS
  arrayD    BYTE    numEl DUP(0h)   ;array (DESTINATION)
  ptr1  DWORD   arrayS
  ptr2  DWORD   arrayD

  startIndex    BYTE    ?        ;store the character in this variable

  exit  EQU     <Invoke ExitProcess,0>
  header    BYTE    "----- Array Copier -----",0
  indexq    BYTE    "Index (0 - 4): ",0
  invalidIn BYTE    "Invalid Input. Try again.",0
  termination   BYTE    "----- Program Terminated -----",0



.code

userInput PROC ;uses ebx ecx eax
beginning:
  mov edx, OFFSET indexq
  call WriteString
  call ReadInt

check:
  mov ebx, 4h           ;check if below 4, then check 2 if below
  cmp eax, ebx
  jbe check2

error:
  mov edx, OFFSET invalidIn
  call WriteString
  call crlf
  jmp beginning

check2:
  mov ebx, 0h       ;check if above zero, then done if above
  cmp eax, ebx
  jnae error

done:
  mov startIndex, al
  ret

userInput ENDP

displayTitle PROC 
  mov edx, OFFSET header        ;displays title
  call WriteString
  call crlf

  ret
displayTitle ENDP

copyArray PROC ;uses ebx ecx 

  mov esi, OFFSET arrayS        ;moving addresses of arrays into the registers
  mov edi, OFFSET arrayD
  add esi, DWORD PTR startIndex
  mov ecx, numEl
  sub ecx, DWORD PTR startIndex

copying:
  mov al, [esi]     ;copying array elements from arrayS to array D
  mov [edi], al
  inc esi
  inc edi
  loop copying

  ret
copyArray ENDP

showArray PROC ;uses ecx 
  mov edi, OFFSET arrayD
  mov ecx, numEl
show:
  mov eax, 0
  mov al, [edi]             ;moving array element to be displayed
  call WriteHex
  mov al, 'h'
  call WriteChar
  call crlf
  add edi, type arrayD      ;moving through array elements to display
  loop show

  ret
showArray ENDP

main PROC
  call displayTitle
  call userInput
  call copyArray
  call showArray

  exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: It would be best to include your source code through copy/paste, instead of showing it in a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This reviews the latest version of the code

In *userInput*, the code in *check2* is totally redundant because the condition of a number ever being below zero is simply not possible.
**Lots of numbers are *less* than zero, but none are *below* zero!**
And you can compare to the hardcoded number 4 without using EBX, but really you should be comparing with *numEl*:

```
check:
  cmp   eax, numEl     ; numEl is 5 in casu
  jb    done           ; We now k n o w that EAX is [0,4]
```

---

In *copyArray*, the byte-sized *startIndex* is being used as if it were a dword. Since you apparantly must keep it a byte, change the code as follows:

```
  mov   edi, OFFSET arrayD
  movzx eax, BYTE PTR startIndex
  mov   esi, OFFSET arrayS
  add   esi, eax
  mov   ecx, numEl
  sub   ecx, eax
copying:
  mov   al, [esi]
  mov   [edi], al
  inc   esi
  inc   edi
  loop  copying
  ret
```

---

In *showArray*, the code displays the full memory for the destination array eventhough probably only a portion of it got filled with copied elements.

```
  mov   ebx, OFFSET arrayD
  movzx eax, BYTE PTR startIndex
  mov   ecx, numEl
  sub   ecx, eax
show:
  movzx eax, BYTE PTR [ebx]
  call  WriteHex
  mov   eax, 'h'
  call  WriteChar
  call  crlf
  inc   ebx
  loop  show
  ret
```

Comment: I am completely shocked, this time it completely works. I really appreciate your time and effort in helping me, including your detailed explanations and the actual syntax to back it up. Sorry for the mix up earlier but you really are the god of assembly, thank you so much

Comment: @crispycalvin Glad I could help you. So that other viewers know that the issue was solved, could you please also click on the acceptance arrow to the left of the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mov al, [esi + startIndex]
> ```

This does not use the byte at the address *startIndex*, but the address of *startIndex* itself.
Before the loop, load the byte in a register:

```
 movzx ebx, startIndex
copying:
 mov   al, [esi + ebx]
 mov   [edi], al
 inc   esi
 inc   edi                <<<< You forgot this one!
 loop  copying
```

Tip: If you define *startIndex* as a `DWORD`, then you can write:

```
 mov   ebx, startIndex
copying:
 mov   al, [esi + ebx]
 mov   [edi], al
 inc   esi
 inc   edi                <<<< You forgot this one!
 loop  copying
```

and also:

```
 mov   edi, OFFSET arrayD
 mov   esi, OFFSET arrayS
 add   esi, startIndex
 mov   ecx, ...
 rep movsb
```

### A further review reveals these additional errors

#### userInput

> ```
> call ReadInt   ; -> EAX
> call crlf
> mov startIndex, al
> ```

It is ok for *crlf* to clobber the EAX register. It could be the case that your *startIndex* doesn't receive the value that the user inputted! Re-arrange your code as follows and define *startIndex* as a DWORD. And performing that check on the inputted number does not require a loop. A single `cmp` can do the job:

```
startIndex  DWORD 0

...

  call ReadInt            ; -> EAX
  cmp  eax, numEl         ; numEl == 5
  jnb  error              ; Not ok if NotBelow 5
  mov  startIndex, eax    ; [0,4]
  call crlf
  jmp  done
error:
```

#### copyArray

The initialization of ECX with *numEl* is only correct if the *startIndex* happens to be 0. But with a greater *startIndex* the number of elements of the array that you *can* copy decreases. If not, you would be copying garbage from outside the arrays.

```
 mov   edi, OFFSET arrayD
 mov   esi, OFFSET arrayS
 add   esi, startIndex
 mov   ecx, numEl
 sub   ecx, startIndex
 rep movsb
```

#### showArray

You forgot to put the address in the EDI register. And here also, you can only sensibly show those elements that were actually copied before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we've had duplicates of this before, where someone hoped `[foo + reg]` would use the integer value at `foo` as an offset to `reg`.  This should be closed, especially given the generic title (many asm bugs have that symptom) and the lack of code in the question (image only.)

Comment: wow, this really worked. thank you so much, you are a god/goddess. I really hope the best for your life

Comment: wait it worked temporarily and i get the message again, is there something I can do about that?

Comment: ^^ the exception thrown comment is now at the mov [edi], al   line

Comment: the reason why startIndex is 8 bits BYTE is because its a specification for my project, which is inconvenient for me. Also, after making these changes, now I get the same message but back on the  mov al, [edi] line

Comment: @crispycalvin I suggest then you copy/paste your newest code in your question. Add it below the current text and certainly don't modify what is already in there!

Comment: @SepRoland I just put in the new, most up to date, code under the question

Comment: @crispycalvin You are **not** applying what I wrote in my answer! Why the *check2* is needed? Why do you think `DWORD PTR startIndex` can help you? Why don't you increment EDI in the copying loop? Why do you read the array element as a dword (it is a byte)?

Comment: @crispycalvin "I just put in the new, most up to date, code under the question" Not really! You have modified the existing code block in the original question. This renders my answering efforts useless. What I asked for is **adding a second code block with the newest version of your program**.

Comment: @SepRoland sorry, i misinterpreted what you said. I just added both, the newest code on the very bottom and the old code on top of it. To clarify, the check 2 is because I don't want the index number falling below 0 (e.g. -1) and I use DWORD PTR startIndex because startIndex must be of BYTE value (specification on my project guideline). The EDI increment also didn't copy over for some reason, I just proofread my code to make sure everything copied. I also apologize if I am being difficult, this is my second month using the language.

Comment: @crispycalvin Just finished reviewing your latest program. I added a second answer for clarity. Hope it works!